# Prove $\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\lt \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

I'm having some trouble figuring out where to start for this proof.

> Prove for all positive integers $n$,
>   $$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\lt \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your inequality is equivalenmt to
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}<\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
this is equivalent to
$$2\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}$$ and we get $$\sqrt{n}<\sqrt{n+1}$$ which is true.

Answer (score 3):

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n} = \frac{\left(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\right)\left(\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}\right)}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n+1}}<\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $$\frac{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}+\sqrt{n}}$$

Comment: Why haven't  you shorten your a hint by giving 1 , that's all :)

Answer (score 1):

According to the MVT there is $x_0$ between $x$ and $x+1$ such that $$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x_0}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Mean Value Theorem with $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}\lt \frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$$
Since $n$ is positive you can multiply both sides by $\frac{1}{2\sqrt{n}}$ to get
$$2\sqrt{n^2+n} - 2n < 1 \Rightarrow$$
$$2\sqrt{n^2+n} < 2n + 1$$
then square both sides (both sides are positive) to get
$$4n^2+4n < 4n^2 + 4n + 1 \Rightarrow$$
$$0 < 1$$