# Help to show relation between ${\sqrt {x + 1}} - {\sqrt x} \leq {\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Show that ${\sqrt{x+1}} - {\sqrt x} \leq {\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$ for all $x \in (0, \infty)$.

I know that the derivative of ${\sqrt x} + 1$ is equal to ${\frac{1}{2\sqrt x}}$. But I don't know if there is another function I should start off with to help me figure out how this inequality works.

Comment: Rationalize the numerator

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2495600/42969.

Answer (score 3):

Use that $$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{x}}$$

Comment: ... as you wrote here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2243982/42969 and here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2495610/42969. Do you *ever* check if a question has been asked before?

Answer (score 0):

$0\lt\dfrac14\implies x(x+1)\lt x^2+x+\dfrac14\implies\sqrt{x(x+1)}<x+\dfrac12$

$\implies \sqrt{x(x+1)}-x<\dfrac12 \implies\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt x\lt\dfrac1{2\sqrt{x}}$

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to use the derivative, apply the mean value theorem:

$$\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{x} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\xi}} \stackrel{x < \xi < x+1}{\leq }\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}} $$